# Mura CMS database connectivity issue inside docker using docker-compose.yml file

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, mura

I am trying to setup Mura CMS using Docker on my local machine. MYSQL database seems not to be working.

I am using the `docker-compose up` command. I have been trying the following example:
https://github.com/blueriver/docker-muracms/tree/master/examples/blueriver-muracms-mysql

```
version: '3.3'

services:

  muracms:
    image: blueriver/muracms:latest
    depends_on:
      - svc_muradb
    environment:
      MURA_ADMIN_USERNAME: admin
      MURA_ADMIN_PASSWORD: 5trongP@55w0rd
      MURA_ADMINEMAIL: youremail@domain.com
      MURA_APPRELOADKEY: appreload
      MURA_DATASOURCE: dsn_muracms
      MURA_DATABASE: muradb
      MURA_DBTYPE: mysql
      MURA_DBUSERNAME: root
      MURA_DBPASSWORD: 5trongP@55w0rd 
      MURA_DBHOST: svc_muradb
      MURA_DBPORT: 3306
      MURA_SITEIDINURLS: "false"
      MURA_INDEXFILEINURLS: "true"
      MURA_TESTBOX: "true"
      MURA_USESSL: "false"
    volumes:
      - ./www/modules:/var/www/modules
      - ./www/plugins:/var/www/plugins
      - ./www/sites:/var/www/sites
      - ./www/themes:/var/www/themes
    ports:
      - "8888:8888"

  # DB
  svc_muradb:
    image: mysql:latest
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: muradb
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 5trongP@55w0rd
    volumes:
      - vol_muradb:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - "5001:3306"

# Mounts
volumes:
  vol_muradb:
```

The following error message I see when I browse localhost:8888:

```
500 Error
Could not create connection to database server.
Code:0
Type:database
lucee.runtime.exp.DatabaseException: Could not create connection to database server.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:918)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:897)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:886)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:860)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because when `muracms` start, the `svc_muradb` still not finish its init.

The `depends_on` just assure `svc_muradb` start first, and then start `muracms`. But the start process `svc_muradb` is asynchronous. So before the `svc_muradb` ready, your `muracms` has probability already want to connect the db.

This issue documented in [official guide](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/), which suggest you to write a wrapper for `svc_muradb` command.

Like follows, I just give you an example:

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: "2"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "80:8000"
    depends_on:
      - "db"
    command: ["./wait-for-it.sh", "db:5432", "--", "python", "app.py"]
  db:
    image: postgres
```

**wait-for-it.sh:**

```
#!/bin/sh
# wait-for-postgres.sh

set -e

host="$1"
shift
cmd="$@"

until PGPASSWORD=$POSTGRES_PASSWORD psql -h "$host" -U "postgres" -c '\q'; do
  >&2 echo "Postgres is unavailable - sleeping"
  sleep 1
done

>&2 echo "Postgres is up - executing command"
exec $cmd
```

With above workaround, the web container will run `wait-for-it.sh`, and first it will try to link its dependency container `db:5432`, only after it confirms can link to database with `psql client`, then it will run the real command `python app.py`.

For your part, you need to change related to `mysql client test`, then everything is ok.

Comment: Not sure what I should add in place of "python", "app.py". Can you tell me what would be that in my case?

Comment: For your scenario: I think it's `command: ["./wait-for-it.sh", "db:xxx", "--", "catalina.sh", "run"]`

Comment: You can use `docker inspect blueriver/muracms:latest` to find the CMD of this image in `Config` section.